# Magento Product import error - SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column ‘entity_id’ cannot be null

Tags: magento, enterprise

When i tried to create new product from Magento backend throwing

```
"Magento Product import error - SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column ‘entity_id’ cannot be null"
```

error, even i have tried to run CSV import but unable to add new products... only update of catalog is working fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can check the CSV file, maybe some problem in entity_id
For your information, you can check first, whether your imported file is correct or not using System > import > product from backend admin page.

Comment: I have checked the CSV file and it is correct format, even when i tried to create manually "simple" product from backend throwing same error.

Answer (score 0):

try creating tab csv instead of comma and also change your dataflow profile to /t option at Value Delimiter: /t because some time comma seperater create problem.

Comment: tried to proposed solution but didn't work, even i unable to create manually product from admin. when i click on SAVE button throwing error "Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column ‘entity_id’ cannot be null".

Comment: finally got the solution.. issue with third party extension just need to commented out below line and every thing is working fine. Mage::helper('sherpaconnect/productDb')->_appendSherpaSyncInformation($product->getId(), $text); location of file: community/Sherpaan/SherpaConnect/Helper/Product.php